# How can I match a char at a specific index in a string?

Tags: java, string

I have a simple string that I'm trying to determine if a specific index results in a specific char.

I'm trying to do it like this (but I get compilation errors):

```
if(myString.charAt(7).equals("/")) {
    // do stuff
} else {
   // do other stuff
}
```

Error:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from char to boolean`

Comment: Is this a direct copy paste from your code? Because that won't compile with it missing a `)` like that.

Comment: `String#charAt()` returns a `char`, not a `String`.

Comment: Thanks, simple typo!  It is NOT a copy and paste from my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(myString.charAt(7).equals("/")
```

should be following because `charAt()` returns char:

```
myString.charAt(7) == '/'
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if(myString.charAt(7)== '/') {
    // do stuff
} else {
   // do other stuff
}
```

Putting a character in double quotes makes it a `String`. Single quotes makes it a `char`. And you compare characters with literal `==` whereas you compare `Objects` with the equals method

Comment: It would probably compile with `.equals()` and autobox it, so be careful! You might run into a significant performance hit if you don't.

Comment: if you run myString.charAt(7).equals('/') it won't autobox it. Rather, you will receive a compilation error that a char cannot be deferenced

Comment: Thanks for explaining the difference in the quotes.

Answer (score 4):

There's a couple solutions on this answer that give you what you were probably trying to do, which is compare a single character to another single character. I won't go over that because they've done excellently.

But you can still use a String if you like, and prepare for the future. (Perhaps "/" changes to "//"?) you can do this:

```
if(myString.substring(7,8).equals("/")) {
    // stuff
}
```

Then down the road you might be like

```
public static final String SEPARATOR_STRING = "//";
public static final int SEPARATOR_START = 7;
public static final int SEPARATOR_END = 7 + SEPARATOR_STRING.length();

// later
if(myString.substring(SEPARATOR_START,7SEPARATOR_END).equals(SEPARATOR_STRING)) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 3):

`charAt()` returns char, not object, so you need to compare it that way:

```
if(myString.charAt(7)== '/') {
...
```

note the single quote around `/`.

Answer (score -2):

```
if(myString.substring(7,8).equals("/"))
```

or

```
if(myString.charAt(7)=='/')
```

or

```
if(myString.indexOf("/"))==7)  can be use
```

Comment: The first is a compilation error, the second is performing an assignment and is therefore incorrect.

Comment: first two are wrong mate. for the reasons @ardentsonata pointed out

Comment: Ohh that's was a terrible mistake. Thank you both for pointing me out :)